# Issue related firebase Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

please help, When i tried same code with same model classes this code run perfectly but it will take many time to connect with firebase app crashed multiple time then connect once but after connecting app run successfully until I change the databasereference name or remove by mistake.....Is is happen every time or just with me????

```
06-22 08:54:46.182 16552-16552/sszj_capricorn.pricecontrolists E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sszj_capricorn.pricecontrolists, PID: 16552
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzNU
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sszj_capricorn.pricecontrolists.Controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is at `MainActivity.java:44`?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: unable to post Answer

Comment: Please edit this to use Markdown formatting (either `>` or a code block).  Also, what have you tried so far?  (Please refer also to Frank van Puffelen's comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //  mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Veg");
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MainActivity.BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MainActivity.BlogViewHolder>(ModelClass.class, R.layout.design_row, MainActivity.BlogViewHolder.class, myRef) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MainActivity.BlogViewHolder viewHolder, ModelClass model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.gettitle());
                    viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                }
            };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://price-control-list-fca08.firebaseio.com/"));
                Intent browserChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Soghat");
                v.getContext().startActivity(browserChooserIntent);
            }

        });
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        post_title.setText(title);

    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack Overflow, is this an answer to this question or is it additional codes regarding the problem? If this is additional code, I suggest you edit your question to paste it at the bottom and deleting this answer.